# C# Excel adds "\" to every space

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using OfficeOpenXml and trying to add custom number format to my cells:

```cs
ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "# ##0.00";
```

But when I stat formatting my document I have `"#\ ##0.00"` number format.
I need value like "123 345 567.89" but have "123456 678.90"

How can I fix this?

Comment: To use a custom thousands separator char, you need to change it in settings. See [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/q/1214264/431599) for more info.

Comment: If that's not good enough and you want to "force it" into Excel from C#, you can do something like this: `var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone(); nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";` and then set the cell value like this `cell.Value = someNumber.ToString("#,##0.00", nfi)`. However, be aware that it will be displayed _as text_ in Excel in that case.

Comment: @41686d6564 i don't think that i can do it. Since Excel file is generated automatically in code

Comment: Well, if you want to display it as a _formatted number_, you must follow the number formatting convention, AFAIK (i.e., thousand separator char is either set in Excel's settings or it's inherited from the system's current culture info. If it's okay with you to display it as text, then you can use the code from my second comment.

Comment: I'm not even going to list this as an answer because I think its too hacky, and not in a cool way. But, you could just provide a format string long enough to cover any numeric length you might encounter. Just add as many 3x# + space as you want. `.Style.Numberformat.Format = "### ### ### ##0.00";`